# Firebase realtime DB update child

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have a "Users" data structure [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ9gd.png), I want to increment the value of `ttl_user` by 1 when a user is signed up. And decrement it by 1 when a user has deleted their account.

How can I update the value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, it would be as simple as:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = db.child("User");
userRef.child("ttl_user").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

And to decrement, simply pass a negative value `-1`.